Passing another parameter to Index action method in ASP.NET MVC
I am able to pass a Search string and a Sort string parameter from Index.cshtml to Index action method in StudentsController. I have added 3 buttons and need to pass either True if button1 or False if button2 or NULL if button3. It is much like Search but boolean (True or False) in buttons' case.
How do I do it in the code shown below?
Index.cshtml:


<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Filter by IsFeatured">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary @((ViewBag.IsFeaturedFilter == null) ? "active" : "")"
                onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Students")'">
            All
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary @((ViewBag.IsFeaturedFilter == true) ? "active" : "")"
                onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Students", new { isFeaturedFilter = true })'">
            Deleted
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary @((ViewBag.IsFeaturedFilter == false) ? "active" : "")"
                onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Students", new { isFeaturedFilter = false })'">
            Not Deleted
        </button>
    </div>



StudentsController:


public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    var students = from m in db.Students select m;

    ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            students = subjects.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentLName );
            break;

        default:
            students = subjects.OrderBy(s => s.StudentFName);
            break;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            students = students .Where(s => s.StudentLName == searchString
                                            || s.StudentFName.Contains(searchString));
        }
    }

    ViewBag.CurrentSearch = searchString;

    return View(students);
}




I would strongly recommend you look at using strongly-typed view model classes to handle all the values you need to pass from a controller method to a view to be rendered. If you need one more item - just add that to the view model class, set it and you're done. Using ViewBag and ViewData is always a bit "fragile" and shaky....

The item IsEnrolled is already in the model and it is rendered on the main page as true or false.  I am just trying to toggle to display either all if IsEnrolled is True or IsEnrolled is False or include both.

To make your life easier, I'd recommend using a view model class to handle all that needs to be passed from the controller to the view to be rendered. Then it's clearly defined, strongly-typed, and you can easily extend it.
Define your view model class like this:
// give it a meaningful name that describes what is being passed
public class StudentSearchViewModel
{
    public string CurrentSearch { get; set; }
    public string NameSortParam { get; set; }

    public bool? BoolSearchParam { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; } 
}

I added the BoolSearchParam as a nullable boolean field - adapt as needed (including naming).
Then in your action method, do this:
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    StudentSearchViewModel vm = new StudentSearchViewModel();

    var students = from m in db.Students select m;

    vm.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            students = subjects.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentLName );
            break;

        default:
            students = subjects.OrderBy(s => s.StudentFName);
            break;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            students = students .Where(s => s.StudentLName == searchString
                                            || s.StudentFName.Contains(searchString));
        }
    }

    vm.CurrentSearch = searchString;
    vm.Students = students;

    vm.BoolSearchParam = ?????;  // set your bool as needed

    return View(vm);
}

And in your view, add this model:
@model StudentSearchViewModel


Thanks, but the only thing I need was to add a bool parameter to the Index in the controller and it seems to work fine.  public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, bool? isFeaturedFilter = null)

Thanks, but the only thing I need was to add a bool parameter to the Index in the controller and it seems to work fine.  public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, bool? isFeaturedFilter = null)

OK, good to hear. But my recommendation still stands: for passing data to be displayed, and possibly data to handle user interactions, from a controller to a view, I would still recommend using a view model class instead of relying on ViewBag and ViewData ...

marc_s - I really like your approach, it makes the code look much simpler and easy to manage.  I will give it a try soon.  Thank you!
